# bringing up network adapter back after ifconfig down

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, interface

When i try bring back my network adapter `ifconfig up` after `ifconfig down` my Internet doesn't resume.I have to reconnect to router to restart it. Why this happens?

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces

interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

$ ifconfig -a

enp19s0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr a4:ba:db:d0:39:b8  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:5185 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5185 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:473578 (473.5 KB)  TX bytes:473578 (473.5 KB)

wlp18s0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c4:46:19:95:3b:0b  
          inet addr:192.168.5.4  Bcast:192.168.5.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:60325 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:39880
          TX packets:34063 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:72845485 (72.8 MB)  TX bytes:2924887 (2.9 MB)
          Interrupt:17 

$ netstat -rn

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
192.168.5.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wlp18s0
```

Comment: `ifdown` and `ifup` enable and disable the interface, if the interface is not configured to auto connect it won't do so. In order to fully answer I think we would need to see your network configuration from /etc/network/interfaces, but if you're using WiFi it might use wpasupplicant or similar depending on what distro you're using.

Comment: using ubuntu 16

Comment: post your `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `ifconfig -a` and `netstat -rn` when you ifconfig up and don't have internet

Comment: @meccooll , you can see the results

Answer (score 0):

You need to pick how you want to manage your connection either manually with ifup ifdown etc... or by network manager as @XtrmJosh has hinted. If you want it to do it yourself and you get IP by DHCP add the following to your `/etc/network/interfaces` files

```
auto enp19s0
iface enp19s0 inet dhcp
```